# Freeform - How to use fieldSearch with table field?

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

I have a table field with handle "attendee".

I would like to search for submissions using data in this field.

None of the below works:

```
$result = Submission::find()->fieldSearch(['attendee'=>'xyz@abc.com'])->all();
$result = Submission::find()->fieldSearch(['attendee[]'=>'xyz@abc.com'])->all();
```

Please help, thanks.